# suggestions on first courses in game theory

Tags: soft-question, game-theory

I am looking for introductory texts in Game Theory. It will my first time studying this, and I prefer the non-economics kind (which I always find in the internet). If there is a biological slant to it, then even better.

Please suggest textbook entries (priority), lecture notes of different courses (secondary).

Thanks

Comment: What did you mean by "the non-economics kind"? Do you just want focus on applications/examples that aren't related to economics? Often people use "the economics kind of game theory" to distinguish from the essentially different field of the study of combinatorial games, but if you want biology applications then you don't want that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An Introduction to game theory by Martin J. Osborne is a very good introductory textbook.
Here's the link: https://www.economics.utoronto.ca/osborne/igt/

Also, these lecture notes by MIT are very good but I'll suggest you go through with the book first, it has theory from basics and pretty good questions too. 
Lectures Link: https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/economics/14-126-game-theory-spring-2016/

Comment: I think if you can make through the MIT notes, then you can handle the more advance text of A Course on Game Theory by Osborne and Rubinestein.

Answer (score 2):

Another standard (and very good) introductory book on Game Theory is Gibbons "Game Theory for Applied Economists," which is circulated in Europe under the title "A Primer in Game Theory."

[Gibbons on Amazon](https://www.amazon.ca/s?k=Gibbons%20game%20theory&ref=nb_sb_noss)

A more gentle introduction to game theory is "Games of Strategy" by Avniash Dixit and Susan Skeath. It puts more emphasis on intuition and less on math. I personally prefer Gibbons, but some students seem to like Dixit's book more.

[Dixiit and Skeath on amazon](https://www.amazon.ca/Games-Strategy-Avinash-Dixit/dp/0393924998/ref=sr_1_7?keywords=strategy%20Dixit&qid=1565998677&s=gateway&sr=8-7)

Answer (score 0):

I second the MIT lecture notes https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/economics/14-126-game-theory-spring-2016/lecture-notes/ and

*An Introductory Course on Mathematical Game Theory* by González-Díaz et al.
https://bookstore.ams.org/gsm-115/